# Double free error detected while cleaning

Tags: c, memory, free

I am getting error while clearing the array

I want to copy all the data of some variables from the `MySettings structure`

```
struct Block {
    int id;  
};
 
struct MySettings {
    int conf_id;
    int group;
    int enable;
    int hide_name;
    int login_persistence;
    int remove_cache;
    struct Block *block;
};
 
 
struct MySettings *Settings[50];
 
void clear(void) {
    puts("Clearing...");
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        if(Settings[i]) {
            if(Settings[i]->block)
                free(Settings[i]->block);
 
            free(Settings[i]);
            Settings[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
}
 
int GetGroupID(int i)
{
    return i;
}
 
void read_db(void) {
    puts("Allocating...");
 
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        struct MySettings *st = calloc(1, sizeof *st);
 
        st->conf_id = i;
 
        st->hide_name = 1;
        st->login_persistence = 1;
        st->remove_cache = 1;
 
        st->block = realloc(st->block, (i + 1) * sizeof *st->block);
        st->block[i].id = i+1;      
 
        for(int g = 0; g < 5; g++) {
            st->group = GetGroupID(g);
            st->enable = 1;
            printf("pointer %p group_id %d enable %s\n", st, st->group, st->enable ? "true" : "false");
 
            Settings[st->group] = st;
        }
 
 
    }
 
    clear();    
}
 
 
int main(void) 
{
    read_db();
    puts("Done...");
    return 0;
}
```

In the `group` and `enable` part, I look for a way for each entry to have a different address

What currently happens is that when I do the for loop using variable `g` all `group` and `enable` generated in this loop have the same address

I want group and enable to always have different addresses

What should I do ?

Comment: `Settings[st->group] = st;` is done in a loop. So, the same memory is added multiple times. In `clear()` you are trying to free `Settings[i]` which will eventually try to free same memory multiple times. Same for `block`

Comment: do you want to have an array of `group` and `enable`? In that case you can't save the pointers in `Settings` using group id. Otherwise clearing will lead to crash. Currently you are generating group id 5 times and ultimately saving the last one in the structure.

Comment: I want multiple `groups` to have the same settings
However, each has a different `group` and `enable` and must have a different address from each other

Comment: So simplest solution would be to have different settings instance for different groups which will have same content except for the group id and enable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible and even easy to do

When you set `Settings[st->group] = st`, the loop will always use the same **address**.

To create an address at each exit of the for loop we need to create a new structure

As for the **double free issue**, we need to create a separate settings cleaning to avoid this type of problem

**Here's the example, based on your code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Block {
    int id;  
};

struct config {
    int conf_id;
    int hide_name;
    int login_persistence;
    int remove_cache;
    struct Block *block;
};
 
struct MySettings {
    int group;
    int enable;
    struct config *conf; 
};
 
struct config *conf[50];
struct MySettings *Settings[50];
 
void clear(void) {
    puts("Cleaning...");
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        if(conf[i]) {
            if(conf[i]->block)
                free(conf[i]->block);
                
            free(conf[i]);
            conf[i] = NULL;
        }
 
        if(Settings[i]) {
            free(Settings[i]);
            Settings[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
}
 
int GetGroupID(int i)
{
    return i;
}
 
void read_db(void) {
    puts("Allocating...");
 
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        struct config *config = calloc(1, sizeof *conf);
 
        config->conf_id = i;
 
        config->hide_name = 1;
        config->login_persistence = 1;
        config->remove_cache = 1;
 
        config->block = realloc(config->block, (i + 1) * sizeof *config->block);
        config->block[i].id = i+1;      
 
        for(int g = 0; g < 5; g++) {
            struct MySettings *st = calloc(1, sizeof *st);
            st->group = GetGroupID(g);
            st->enable = 1;
            st->conf = config;
            printf("pointer %p pointer conf %p group_id %d enable %s\n", st, st->conf, st->group, st->enable ? "true" : "false");
 
            Settings[st->group] = st;
        }
 
        conf[config->conf_id] = config;
    }
 
    clear();    
}
 
 
int main(void) 
{
    read_db();
    puts("Done...");
    return 0;
}
```

I have the following output from this code:

```
Allocating...
pointer 0x55e6ed1d62b0 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6270 group_id 0 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d62d0 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6270 group_id 1 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d62f0 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6270 group_id 2 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6310 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6270 group_id 3 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6330 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6270 group_id 4 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6390 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6350 group_id 0 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d63b0 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6350 group_id 1 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d63d0 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6350 group_id 2 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d63f0 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6350 group_id 3 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6410 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6350 group_id 4 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6470 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6430 group_id 0 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6490 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6430 group_id 1 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d64b0 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6430 group_id 2 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d64d0 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6430 group_id 3 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d64f0 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6430 group_id 4 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6550 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6510 group_id 0 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6570 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6510 group_id 1 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6590 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6510 group_id 2 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d65b0 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6510 group_id 3 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d65d0 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6510 group_id 4 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6630 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d65f0 group_id 0 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6650 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d65f0 group_id 1 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6670 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d65f0 group_id 2 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6690 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d65f0 group_id 3 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d66b0 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d65f0 group_id 4 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6710 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d66d0 group_id 0 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6730 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d66d0 group_id 1 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6750 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d66d0 group_id 2 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6770 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d66d0 group_id 3 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6790 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d66d0 group_id 4 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6800 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d67b0 group_id 0 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6820 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d67b0 group_id 1 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6840 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d67b0 group_id 2 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6860 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d67b0 group_id 3 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6880 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d67b0 group_id 4 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d68f0 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d68a0 group_id 0 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6910 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d68a0 group_id 1 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6930 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d68a0 group_id 2 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6950 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d68a0 group_id 3 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6970 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d68a0 group_id 4 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d69e0 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6990 group_id 0 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6a00 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6990 group_id 1 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6a20 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6990 group_id 2 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6a40 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6990 group_id 3 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6a60 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6990 group_id 4 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6ad0 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6a80 group_id 0 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6af0 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6a80 group_id 1 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6b10 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6a80 group_id 2 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6b30 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6a80 group_id 3 enable true
pointer 0x55e6ed1d6b50 pointer conf 0x55e6ed1d6a80 group_id 4 enable true
Clearing...
Done...
```

This should work as expected

Comment: I tested it and it works as I said in the post, thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 0):

> I want group and enable to always have different addresses

In that case you can't have `Settings[st->group] = st;` in a loop **without** a new `struct MySettings *st = calloc(1, sizeof *st);`. Your current code adds the same pointer (i.e. `st`) five times.

You need to move the inner `for` loop to the top. Something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for(int g = 0; g < 5; g++) {
        struct MySettings *st = calloc(1, sizeof *st);

        .... 
        ....
    }
}
```

If you want all object pointers in `Settings` to point to different objects (i.e. point to different addresses) you must have one `st = calloc(...)` before each `Settings[st->group] = st;`.

Comment: Is there no other way without moving the inner loop?

Comment: No. The address of `group` and `enable` is determined by the address of `st`. In other words.... as long as `st` isn't changed (using a new `calloc`) the address of `group` and `enable` is the same. You need a `st = calloc...` to change the addresses.

Comment: @Michael I'm not sure what your goal is but if you want to have multiple `enable` and `group` associated with a single `st`, you must either change them to be arrays or change them to be pointers and allocate a dynamic array.

Comment: I like the pointer with dynamic allocation better, in this case I would have to remove `group` and `enable` from the `structure of MySettings` ?

Could you show me an example?

Comment: @Michael As I don't understand what your goal for this code is, I'm not able to come up with a solution. You can perhaps ask a new question where you clearly describe what your goal for code is and ask for help on reaching the goal. Abyway... notice if you do multiple `Settings[st->group] = st;` for the **same** `st`, you will get into double-free problems. To avoid that you need another method for freeing objects.